# Auto Play Youtube Embedded Video without editing the embedding code

Tags: wordpress, video, youtube, embed

I am working on a music site for a client (in Wordpress), and they would like the 'Featured Youtube video' that will display on the homepage to autoplay when the page loads. I'm looking for a solution that wouldn't require client to edit the code when they paste the embedding code for Youtube. Is there a way I can hard code this to my template files?

Most solutions out there are about editing the code to enable autoplay. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could manipulate the html using jQuery, you would target the element and insert the html required to autoplay, this way it can be inserted each time the page loads.

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_html.asp) and this [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) link should get you going.